# How to add displayName to a user immediately after signing up the user in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I made a ref to the name of the person using `useRef`. This is my code:

```
try {
  await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  user.updateProfile({
    displayName: nameOfUserRef,
  });
  history.push("/");
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

What I expect: I expect that the newly added user' displayName will get changed to `nameOfUserRef`

What is happening: It is not throwing an error but when I console log `user.displayName`, it shows `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`updateProfile()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateprofile) method is asynchronous and returns a Promise, so you should use `await`, as you did for the asynchronous `signup()` method:

```
try {
  await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  await user.updateProfile({
    displayName: nameOfUserRef,
  });
  console.log(user.displayName)  <= Should be ok here
  history.push("/");
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: It is showing an error saying: `auth.esm.js:82 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.replace (<anonymous>) `